# After installing JDK9 my eclipse stopped working

Tags: eclipse, java-9

Currently i am using neon eclipse and it was working. Today i installed Java9 and after that i am unable to open my eclipse workspace. When i look at the workspace .metadata/.log i am seeing the below error. How do i resolve this?

```
 org.eclipse.e4.core.di.InjectionException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/annotation/PostConstruct
        at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:386)
        at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.make(InjectorImpl.java:294)
        at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.make(ContextInjectionFactory.java:162)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createDefaultHeadlessContext(E4Application.java:490)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createDefaultContext(E4Application.java:504)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createE4Workbench(E4Application.java:203)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:632)
        at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:610)
        at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:148)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:138)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:673)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:610)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1519)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/annotation/PostConstruct
        at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.inject(InjectorImpl.java:151)
        at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:375)
        ... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.annotation.PostConstruct cannot be found by org.eclipse.e4.core.di_1.6.1.v20160712-0927
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:410)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:372)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:364)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:161)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:496)
        ... 24 more
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40492235/cannot-create-eclipse-workspace/40510756#40510756

Comment: the other option is to add the below vm argument to eclipse.ini file                "-vm
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_101.jdk/Contents/Home/bin"