# clientBuilder.sslSocketFactory not supported on JDK 9+

Tags: eclipse, maven, java-9

I get following error on my project in Eclipse 4.7.0. I have

```
jdk-9_windows-x64_bin.exe
```

Resource: pom.xml

```
Mavan dependency Problem (1 item)
clientBuilder.sslSocketFactory not supported on JDK 9+
```

on mvn clean install

```
 in http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository
, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM
 @ line 5, column 10 -> [Help 2]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
[ERROR] [Help 2] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/UnresolvableModelException
```

Comment: You get the error during what? `mvn install`? and could you share more of the log trace please

Comment: eclipse build my project automatically, i get this problem by Markers window of eclipse. If i try to install maven: i get Error: Could not find or load main class org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher

Comment: does running `mvn clean install` also results in a similar failure?

Comment: Are you [starting Eclipse using JDK9](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40493168/1746118)? [Similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40492235/cannot-create-eclipse-workspace)

Comment: *'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM* seems to be an issue with the specified parent in your `pom.xml`

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. It happened to me when I tried to start Eclipse with Java 9. Make sure Maven is updated, the latest version should support Java 9.

If your goal is to develop Java 9 applications, you can do so while Eclipse is still running with Java 8. For Eclipse Oxygen 4.7.1 you had to install the now obsolete and no longer available [Java 9 Support for Oxygen](https://web.archive.org/web/20180511042948/https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/java-9-support-oxygen/) feature.

Since Oxygen.1a (4.7.1a) Eclipse supports Java 9 by default, so you should update Eclipse.

Comment: The page you mentioned does not exist. It throws 404.

Comment: @HemantNagpal Thanks, I've updated the answer. The answer is kind of obsolete anyway since it only applied for the old 4.7.1 version.

Comment: Donot understand this error - I get the same issue when creating maven project with archetype selection. I DONT have java 9 on my system (eclipse points to java 8 for start and Workspace also on java8). As a workaround, create simple maven project (ie skip archetype selection)