# Failed to create project. clientBuilder.sslSocketFactory(SSLSocketFactory) not supported on JDK 9+

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

im using eclipse Version: Oxygen.3a Release (4.7.3a)
Build id: 20180405-1200
JRE installed is java 10 
compiler compliance is java 10

when I create maven project with jersey archetype I get the following error.

```
Failed to create project.
clientBuilder.sslSocketFactory(SSLSocketFactory) not supported on JDK 9+
```

while **creating jersey-quickstart-webapp error has encountered**.

other questions in stackoverflow seems to be different problem or not solving my issue please help.
[question does not solve as the given link is broken and I dono what to update as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46396382/clientbuilder-sslsocketfactory-not-supported-on-jdk-9)

Comment: please add your research in StackOverflow...

Comment: Have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46396382/clientbuilder-sslsocketfactory-not-supported-on-jdk-9

Comment: I think my eclipse is started using java 9 only I can see new features.

Comment: I get the same issue when creating maven project with archetype selection. I DONT have  java 9 on my system (eclipse points to java 8 for start and Workspace also on java8). As a workaround, create simple maven project (ie skip archetype selection)